# vba: searching data in column

Tags: excel, vba

My situation is:
I've got two spreadsheets with A1:A10(column) and B1:B10(column) in first spreadsheet and A1:A5(column) in second one filled with data. I need to search my every element of my A1:A5 cells in A1:A10 column. If element exists, copy data from first spreadsheed same row cell in column B to my second spreadsheet column B by the same element.

Should I use "For" loop to count every element in A1:A5 column or is there any other function in VB? I'm very new to it. A1:A10 column range could be different so I need to stop the function when whole column is checked.

Comment: Why doing this with VBA when there is a `VLOOKUP` function, or `MATCH`  and `INDEX`?

Comment: Because I need one button to run all this function. Is there any possibilities to do that with VLOOKUP, MATCH and INDEX?

Comment: Why a button when Excel can do it in real-time?